# Link css and js of a template (from vendor) to my views

Tags: laravel, templates, adminlte

### This worked when I added the template in the public folder **BUT** what I m asking for is the proper way of doing things.

I created a new laravel project ,and I want to use Adminlte 3 as a template ,so I run this command that i found in the documentation  :

```
composer require "almasaeed2010/adminlte=~3.1"
```

response ( I think last 2 lines maybe useful )

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update almasaeed2010/adminlte
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking almasaeed2010/adminlte (v3.1.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading almasaeed2010/adminlte (v3.1.0)
  - Installing almasaeed2010/adminlte (v3.1.0): Extracting archive
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/sanctum
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravel/ui
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
77 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force
No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].
Publishing complete.
```

I found out that a new folder was added to my vendor folder .
Everything is downloaded correctly , so I tried to create a Master page that contains all the repeated elements of the dashboard but , the links I used are not dynamic so I m not sure if its gonna cause problems if the views are in different directory level. for example :

this is the Admin lte 3 link to css :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
```

how I called it like this :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ require('C:\Users\Yasser-Ch\Desktop\LaravelProject\gestionDivers\vendor\almasaeed2010\adminlte\dist\css\adminlte.min.css') }}">
```

and this made the page look like the css file so tried put it inside the `resources\css\app.css`
and of course it didn't work because css is not .blad.php  ,so I thought maybe composer ( because in the documentation says exactly :

> *The vendor directory contains your Composer dependencies.*

) or something else can interpret it and put only what I need from the "vendor\almasaeed2010" (the template in general ) and put it in 2 files 1 for css and 1 for js ... I did some researches and I found mix … 
So I tried this :

```
  {{ mix.postCss('\vendor\almasaeed2010\adminlte\dist\css\adminlte.min.css', 'public/css') }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="adminlte.min.css">
```

Then I run these commands :

```
  npm install // to download mix that is by default already required in the package.json 
  npm run dev // and here I expect mix to start mixing
```

I check the public/css has only app.css added . And when I re run the website using `php artisan serve` I get an error that says mix is undefined .
I mean mix didn't cause an error during `npm run dev` .I would delete it ,if it did the job of mixing before starting the server .
How to link the css/js from the vendor ? should I publish everything inside the public folder ?
Because I think the fact that they put the template inside the vendor folder means it shouldn't be directly in the public directory.

Comment: If any one is stuck on this, and nothing here helped,  see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ipu43Qo-C0) . Using `npm` and not `composer` everything is  much easier , just read [this](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/) step by step , and add `{{ asset('css/app.css') }}` in the css link tag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webpack for that, check file `webpack.mix.js` add or search line like below

```
// webpack.mix.js
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

// in 'app.scss
// import all necessary css files 
@import 'vendor\almasaeed2010\adminlte\dist\css\adminlte.min.css'
```

run `npm install` if never, then run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`.
It will create `app.css` in `public/css`

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: i didn't know that `webpack.mix.js`  is where i put the mix calls. So for the js files i do `require('vendor\almasaeed2010\adminlte\dist\js\adminlte.min.js');` in app.js  and call it like `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`  ?

Comment: after adding  `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')`

Comment: Did it work now?